# Is opengl cross platform? If not, how a game be ported?

Tags: c++, opengl, cross-platform, porting

Ok, so say I'm writing a game in c++ with opengl. The game draws a few, simple shapes like squares on the screen. Now say I want to run the "game" on windows. How would I go about porting it? The actual c++ wouldn't be the problem, as it can be recompiled to fit the environment from what I understand. But the calls to the openGL library would be broken wouldn't they? The actual opengl library which would be included for development woul be compiled for the os, which would necessitate redownloading the library, which would lead to modifications to the source. Which would break the program on the original environment, right?

tl;dr Is there any way to build an opengl game for multiple operating systems without having to modify the source code to be platform specific or downloading external wrappers or libraries?

Comment: I don't think your opinion to close the question is right

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OpenGL is platform independent, rather than cross platform. It is just a specification for the interface of a graphics library. It has no concern for the platform it is being implemented on. It just describes functions, what they're called and what they do.

Specific implementations of the OpenGL library may be cross platform or may be not. For example, [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/) is cross platform to some degree, despite being mainly developed for Linux. You'll need to find implementations of OpenGL on each of the platforms you want to compile on.

However, there is some code that needs to be executed *before* you can start using the OpenGL interface. This code is for setting up the OpenGL rendering context. How you do that *is* platform specific. For example, on Linux, GLX is an extension to the X Window System that provides an interface for creating the rendering context. This will only work on systems that are running the X Window System. On other systems, you will have to do something different to do the same job.

There are cross platform libraries for doing this job of creating the rendering context for you. For example, take a look at [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/). It's a modern alternative to a library called GLUT, but GLUT is not maintained any longer. You can avoid having platform specific code in your source and give that job to the library to manage.

Note that OpenGL only provides a graphics library. Nothing more. There may be many other libraries and interfaces that a game uses that will not be platform independent, such as input, sound, etc. If your game only contains pure C++ and the only library is OpenGL then the source may port very smoothly to another platform, as long as your C++ code doesn't rely on  any unspecified behaviour. You may not even have to change the rendering context set up if you used a library like GLFW.

It's also worth mentioning things like [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) and [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/). These libraries are cross-platform and provide an interface for all sorts of multimedia. They will set up your OpenGL rendering context, create windows for you, draw to the screen, deal with I/O and sound, and much more. They can be limited in some respects, but they're powerful in that they get you to a great position on all platforms very quickly.

Comment: Hm, so you're saying that if I want to make a game available for another os I need to switch to the target os and recode the project, but using an implementation of opengl for the platform?

Comment: Not recode, but recompile. You can write cross-platform C++ that contains platform specific code. This is usually done with the proprocessor. For example, you can have something like `#ifdef LINUX` wrapping some Linux specific code. Build systems often provide a means to do this. (You can technically also compile to different target platforms but this can be a pain)

Comment: You always have to *recompile* the project. OpenGL is a *specification*, not a *library*. For example, the Nvidia drivers *implement* this specification on Windows as well as on Linux and Mac OS X by the drivers.

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 You'd probably be better off using a library that abstracts away things like creating the window. For me five years ago this was GLUT, but there's probably a modern alternative.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin The most modern library I came across is Qt3D, a library which implements even a whole scene graph, material abstractions (default shaders) and much, much more. It's cross-platform also for mobile phones and stuff..

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Yeah, I just added a bit about GLFW.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and clarifications, I was actually asking this because I'm comin from java, where everything's cross platform and the VM takes care of the platform-specific stuff. I have/had no idea how the need for a recompilation of the code affected/affects the development process.

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 It's not as nightmarish as you think if you use cross-platform libraries to do everything. Use a cross-platform implementation of OpenGL, a cross-platform library for setting up the rendering context and windows, a cross-platform I/O library, a cross-platform sound library, etc. and you'll be fine. Whenever there's a time you think you need to write platform specific code, there's probably a library that will already do it for you.

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 Please also see my edits - particularly about SFML.

Comment: I was actually looking at sfml a few hours ago, but I was turned off by its lack of instructions on how to use it with eclipse (stupid reason I know). Just a little more though. By rendering context do you mean the window everything is drawn in? Or something else?

Comment: @pipsqueaker117 No, the rendering context is basically the *state* of your OpenGL graphics. The functions that OpenGL provides are used to modify or inspect that state. The state needs to be created before the OpenGL interface can be used. It is in some way linked to the window it'll be drawn in.

Comment: Hm. Thanks. Also, why would I need sfml for displaying things in windows? The built in Display of openGl seems to work pretty well. Stackoverflow is starting to warn me about extended chat discussions, so this is going to (hopefully) be my last comment. Again, thanks for everybody's patience and answers, especially yours, sftrabbit. Cya.

Comment: @pipsqueaker117: OpenGL does not deal with creating a window or setting up a drawable. Essentially it's just pencils brushes and stencils to draw on a canvas provided by the OS through other means.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, OpenGL is cross platform. The code to create an OpenGL rendering context, handling input, et.al., its usually not.

Comment: So you're saying that if I take an opengl project that I coded on a Mac, copied it to windows and set it up with eclipse, swapped out the Lib files with the ones for windows, and recompiled the project I'd be fine?

Comment: @pipsqueaker117: If you do that, what then...? It would only work if everything else other than **OpenGL** is cross platform as well.

Comment: I was thinking using c++ and opengl. Nothing else. And also, when you say that handling inpt is t cross platform, are you saying that things like keyboard events require different code for every os? I don't think that's what you mean, but that's all I can get from it...

Comment: I think keyboard handling, audio and other such things are EXACTLY what K-ballo is talking of.

Comment: @pipsqueaker117: Yes, that's what I mean, and that's the way it is. Creating windows, receiving input (like keyboard/mouse/touch), and that kind of stuff requires different code for every OS. Unless you are building on top a cross-platform library that already provides such different code for every OS.

Comment: Oh wow... I'm beginning to get a glimpse of how nightmarish game development must be...

Comment: @pipsqueaker117: Actually the whole OS interaction stuff makes only a small portion of a game engine. Maybe 5% tops. It's not really difficult and can be very good modularized out.